# HttpMessageNotWritableException No serializer found for JavassistLazyInitializer

Tags: spring-mvc, jackson

I have exception

```
org.springframework.http.converter.HttpMessageNotWritableException: Could not write content: No serializer found for class org.hibernate.proxy.pojo.javassist.JavassistLazyInitializer and no properties discovered to create BeanSerializer (to avoid exception, disable SerializationFeature.FAIL_ON_EMPTY_BEANS) )
```

But I've already disable SerializationFeature.FAIL_ON_EMPTY_BEANS feature.

Here is my servlet-context.xml

```
    <beans:bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter">
        <beans:property name="messageConverters">
            <beans:list>
                <beans:ref bean="jsonMessageConverter"/>
            </beans:list>
        </beans:property>
    </beans:bean>

    <!-- Configure bean to convert JSON to POJO and vice versa -->
    <beans:bean id="jsonMessageConverter" class="org.springframework.http.converter.json.MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter">
        <beans:property name="objectMapper" ref="jacksonObjectMapper" />
    </beans:bean>

    <beans:bean id="jacksonObjectMapper" class="controllers.MyJsonMapper"></beans:bean>
```

And custom ObjectMapper

```
public class MyJsonMapper extends ObjectMapper {

    public MyJsonMapper() {
        this.configure(SerializationFeature.FAIL_ON_EMPTY_BEANS, false);
    }

}
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: did you find the answer ?